# Automating Internet Explorer via VBA for Windows 11

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, windows-11

I realise there are other threads for this but I coudnt see a *complete* answer for my circumstances after searching a few hours, just lots of "will try this or this"

I have a significant number of web scrapers written using VBA to run IE, which I share with various non-computer literate co-workers. What is the simplest way to get them working on Windows 11 assuming Selenium is not an option (too difficult to set up and install for my end users) and converting to python isn't possible due to the amount of re-writing.

Is there a simple way to re-write the codes, or some way to reintroduce IE? Short example below

```
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.navigate ("https://example.com/login")
IE.Visible = True
Call IEWait

Sub IEWait()

cTime = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")

Do Until (IE.ReadyState = 4 And Not IE.Busy)
    If Now < cTime Then
        DoEvents
    
    Else
        
        IE.navigate ("htpps://example.com/logout")
        IE.Quit
        Set IE = Nothing
        MsgBox "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: AFAIK internet explorer isn't a thing on Windows 11, I believe edge now has a compatibility tool, but I think you need Selenium to interface with it through VBA.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to inform you that on Windows 11 OS, you will not get Internet Explorer browser but the MSHTML (Trident) engine(underlying platform for Internet Explorer 11) will be there on Windows 11 OS and continue to be supported (in other words, unaffected by this announcement).

> As part of the IE 11 application retirement, certain COM automation
> scenarios were inadvertently broken. These IE COM objects have been
> restored to their original functionality as of the Windows 11 November
> 2021 "C" update and the Windows 10 February 2022 "B" update (for
> versions 1809 and later). The COM scenarios will also continue to work
> after the IE11 desktop application is disabled after June 15, 2022.

Based on the above information, your VBA IE automation code will continue to work on Windows 11 OS. You do not need to configure any special settings for that, just make sure that Windows 11 OS has latest updates installed on it. You could try to run the code in a similar way as you are running on other Windows OS(e.g. Windows 10). When you run your VBA IE automation code on Windows 11 OS , it will also launch the same UI interface as Internet Explorer browser.

Reference: [Internet Explorer 11 desktop app retirement FAQ](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549)

Let me know if you are facing an issue while running your VBA code on Windows 11 OS. I will try to provide suggestions to fix it.